# Set list field permission

Tags: security, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

So you don't have programming privileges on a SharePoint Server but you can use SharePoint Designer.  You create lists and you need to separate field permissions.  You need fields that all can fill out and fields for administrators to fill out.  How do you accomplish this **without** code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this blog post from Laura Rogers](http://web.archive.org/web/20091211181836/http://spinsiders.com/laurar/2009/01/23/displaying-sharepoint-fields-by-permission-level). It shows you how to display (and therefore edit) fields according to permission level using SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be awkward.

There is no such functionality out of the box but you can spoof it using multiple lists and workflows.
Something like:

1 list for admins with all fields
1 list for users with user fields

Tie these together with workflows: users have rights on the user list, they can add an entry that fires a workflow that creates or updates an entry in the admin list, copying in all the fields. 
You should be able to create these workflows with SharePoint designer.